# assigning float into int variable causes no warning

Tags: c, types, warnings, implicit-conversion

So, given the following code:

```
int main(void) {
  int i;
  i = 12.1234;
  i++;
  return 0;
}
```

I compiled the code and I expected and wanted the compiler to give me a warning, but it didn't. Is my compiler configured wrong? Is there a way to make my compiler give warning?

This is what I used

> cc -Wall test.c

Comment: `-Wconversion` if supported, you don't mention which compiler.

Comment: @ShafikYaghmour gcc on MS Windows. I can verify that -Wconversion works.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A float value **can be assigned** to an integer variable but an **implicit conversion** occurs when **compiler** forces a float value to be assigned as an integer.

The digits after the decimal notation in the float value get lost after assigning a float to an integer.

Edit: casting -> conversion

Thanks R..

Comment: *Implicit conversion*, not *implicit casting*. The definition of a cast is an operator which performs an explicit conversion. Implicit casting is an oxymoron.

Comment: Should it not produce a warning by default i.e. without Wconversion ? I see clang produce this warning by default

Answer (score 6):

Since you confirmed your compiler is `gcc` then you can use the [-Wconversion](https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/NewWconversion) flag which should provide a warning similar to this:

```
warning: conversion to 'int' alters 'double' constant value [-Wfloat-conversion]
i = 12.1234;
    ^
```

Converting a floating point value to *int* is perfectly valid it will discard the fractional part and as long as the value can be represented, otherwise you have undefined behavior. The C99 draft standard covers this in section `4.9` *Floating-integral conversions*:

> A prvalue of a floating point type can be converted to a prvalue of an
>   integer type. The conversion truncates; that is, the fractional part
>   is discarded. The behavior is undefined if the truncated value cannot
>   be represented in the destination type.

Answer (score 0):

You may expect that `-Wall` does enable *ALL* warnings, but it doesn't!
There are a lot of warnings that doesn't even make sense in the wrong environment.

It is an aggregation of the following flags:

> ```
>   -Waddress   
>   -Warray-bounds (only with -O2)  
>   -Wc++11-compat  
>   -Wchar-subscripts  
>   -Wenum-compare (in C/ObjC; this is on by default in C++) 
>   -Wimplicit-int (C and Objective-C only) 
>   -Wimplicit-function-declaration (C and Objective-C only) 
>   -Wcomment  
>   -Wformat   
>   -Wmain (only for C/ObjC and unless -ffreestanding)  
>   -Wmaybe-uninitialized 
>   -Wmissing-braces (only for C/ObjC) 
>   -Wnonnull  
>   -Wparentheses  
>   -Wpointer-sign  
>   -Wreorder   
>   -Wreturn-type  
>   -Wsequence-point  
>   -Wsign-compare (only in C++)  
>   -Wstrict-aliasing  
>   -Wstrict-overflow=1  
>   -Wswitch  
>   -Wtrigraphs  
>   -Wuninitialized  
>   -Wunknown-pragmas  
>   -Wunused-function  
>   -Wunused-label     
>   -Wunused-value     
>   -Wunused-variable  
>   -Wvolatile-register-var
> ```
>
> as described here: https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.8.2/gcc/Warning-Options.html

What you need is `-Wconversion` as mentioned above. Another quite useful flag may be `-Wextra`.