# Inconsistent casting on iOS in debug and release

Tags: ios, xcode, casting

For my games I store angles in a short (so they'll automatically wrap for me), which makes 90 degrees +16384, and 270 degrees -16384 etc... But, if you run this code on iOS:

```
int     iDegrees;
short   iAngle;

iDegrees = 270;

iAngle = (float)(iDegrees) * 65536.0f / 360.0f;
```

in Debug mode on both the simulator and a real device iAngle is -16384, as I'd expect. But in Release mode on the simulator iAngle is 255, and on a device it's 0.

Is this a bug in Xcode generating the code???

update:

I found if you cast the float to an int (and then the compiler casts that to a short) it gives the result I'd expect:

```
iAngle = (int)((float)(iDegrees) * 65536.0f / 360.0f);
```

It seems iOS doesn't like casting an overflowed float to a short - but only in Release mode!

Comment: by the way, putting parentheses around `iDegrees` does nothing. This could be related to target architecture, optimization, compiler etc.

Comment: Per https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24915712/assigning-float-into-int-variable-causes-no-warning/24916010 this behavior is undefined in C if the truncated value (that is, after removing the decimal part) cannot be represented in the target type. You should turn on conversion warnings in Xcode.

Comment: Thanks, I guess a float of over 32767.0f can't be expressed as a short, but with my fix I'm casting that float to an int which can be, and then casting that resulting int to a short gives me the wrap around I'm after. It's annoying that on iOS Debug and Release give different results though, and it's even different between a device and the simulator!

Comment: That's exactly what "undefined behavior" means. It can behave randomly, especially under optimizations in release mode. Your solution is correct. You have to explicitly cast the float before assigning it to a short variable. Turn on all the warnings you can. They will warn you about dangerous casts.

Comment: Thanks Sulthan, that all makes sense